# Creating a Node for Linked List/Self Referential Structures

Tags: c, nodes

I'm trying to create a node to create a linked list, but I'm getting the error

"IntelliSense: a value of type "void *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "C"" 
Isn't the value of C which is a synonym for B: NULL not void?
Therefore shouldn't the initial node be created with NULL and then manipulation of the linked list will occur?

I haven't continued the insert function because the creation of the node is not working

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct A
{
    char data;
    struct A *nextPtr;
};

typedef struct A B;
typedef B *C;

void insert(C *sPtr, char value);
void print(C cPtr);
void menu(void);

int main (void)
{
    menu();
    C startPtr = NULL;
    char c;
    int x;
    for (x = 0; x <6; x++)
    {
        insert(&startPtr, c);
        print(startPtr);
    }
}

void menu(void)
{
    puts("Enter 1 to Add: \nEnter 2 to Remove \nEnter 3 to quit");
}

void print (C cPtr)
{
    puts("Names in the List");
    printf("%c ->",cPtr->data);
}

void insert(C *sPtr, char value)
{
    C nPtr;
    C pPtr;
    C cPtr;
    nPtr = malloc( sizeof (B));
}
```

Comment: Are you actually getting a compilation error? Or just an intellisense warning? Also, a few suggestions: Use more meaningful names than `A`, `B`, `C`. Best to avoid typedefing pointers, but if you must, at least indicate that it is a pointer in the typedef name.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36757535/971127

Comment: Compilation error
I'm just following the example in our book and trying to get a node initialized. So instead of typing out a longer name, I was trying to just keep things easy to follow.

Comment: `char data[10];` --> `char data;`

Comment: BluePixy: I am compiling it in C, and have redone the program multiple times in C, so his fix did not work for me

Comment: immibis: C
BLUEPIXY: are you saying i should change     char data[10] to char data?

Comment: code is supposed to `char data;`. E.g. `printf("%c ->",cPtr->data);`

Comment: g++ is compiling this without any errors. What are you using? Did you try type casting?

Comment: Nandakumar: Visual Studio 2013
BLUEPIXY: Yes? I changed the it to  'char data[10]' to see if it would do anything but it didnt. You are correct it should be 'char data'

Comment: @kaylum are you saying that I should have used 
   typedef struct A * B;
?

Comment: The Code example I am referencing to is the same code from this example from my book/lecture slides: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24511625/creating-a-node-list?rq=1

Comment: @Nandakumar g++ was output **error: invalid conversion from 'void*' to 'C {aka A*}'**  (Such an error if you use the C compiler is not output.)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Yes, I see the error now. But it compiled and run somehow. That's why I didn't notice it.